# Eating a dot after a command

Tags: macros

I have a bibliography in which URLs are printed with a following "." I would like to omit the URLs to save space and I could do this by redefining the URL command, but this would leave me with a dot. Is there a way to define a command that eats a following "."?

Comment: If all the URLs are in the form `\url{...}.`, then redefine `\url` with two arguments to do nothing with them. Otherwise something slightly more complicated should be done.

Comment: Maybe you can pick or design a bibliography style that will omit the `url` fields? That would look like a more natural way of doing it, for example in case you have urls elsewhere in your text.

Comment: I have a bibliography that contains URLs they are set like `\url{ ... }.` I cannot influence this. So I have to redifine the url command to eat this dot.

Comment: @StefanMüller: but it should be easy to modify your bibliography style file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- The redefinition of `\url` is not trivial, because the argument might contain the 
  percent character. Therefore the argument needs to be read with verbatim catcodes.
- The dot can be removed using `\@ifnextchar.\@gobble{}`. This also catches the case that `\url{...}` is *not* followed by a dot. As side effect `\@ifnextchar` removes spaces. This can be avoided by using `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` of package `ltxcmds` instead of `\@ifnextchar`.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\urlgobble}{%
  \begingroup
    % set verbatim catcodes
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    % restore catcode of argument braces
    \catcode`\{=1 %
    \catcode`\}=2 %
    \@urlgobble
}
\newcommand*{\@urlgobble}[1]{%
  % eats the URL in #1
  \endgroup
  % skip an optional dot
  \@ifnextchar.\@gobble{}%
}
\newcommand*{\skipurls}{\let\url\urlgobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Normal url:
  \url{http://www.example.org/Hello%20World.html}

\skipurls
Skipped urls:
  \url{http://www.example.net/Hello%20World.html}
  \url{http://www.example.com/Hello%20World.html}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Great answer (as usual); I've changed `\urlgobble` into `\url` in the final example, which seemed to be your intent, as `\skipurl` was given.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, it was a leftover from testing that I have forgotten to revert.

Answer (score 5):

Works only if the URL has no special characters!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\url{http://www.dante.de}.

\makeatletter
\let\URL\url
\def\url#1{\@ifnextchar.\url@i{\url@i.}}
\def\url@i.{}
\makeatother

Not printed: \url{http://www.dante.de}.

\URL{http://www.dante.de}

\end{document}
```

[image]