# Space that disappears at the edges (beginning/end) of a math formula

Tags: math-mode, symbols, logic

**Is there a way to produce a space that disappears at the beginning or end of a math formula?**

> **Idea:** For the formula-final case, something that looks ahead or takes an obligatory argument might be a start. I remember that commands whose obligatory arguments are terminated by the end of a math formula will be fed empty arguments.

Some practical examples:

---

### Example 1

The uniqueness quantifier ("there exists exactly one") is often written "∃!".

Out of visual considerations I would like the following variable to be a bit away from the exclamation mark, to make it clearer that "∃!" is considered a single token ("token" here in the sense of parsing in a programming language). I can define something like `\newcommand*{\existsunique}{\exists!\mskip1.5mu\relax}`, but the space of `1.5mu` remains if the symbol is used by itself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % better spacing behavior for \colon
\usepackage{dsfont}

\newcommand*{\existsunique}{\exists!\mskip1.5mu\relax}


\begin{document}

% spacing (1.5mu) as desired
\(\forall x \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  \existsunique y \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  y^2 = x\)

% spacing (0mu) too tight
\(\forall x \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  \exists! y \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  y^2 = x\)

% spacing (1.5mu) superfluous
The quantifier \(\existsunique\) means ``there is exactly one''.

% spacing (0mu) as desired
The quantifier \(\exists!\) means ``there is exactly one''.

\end{document}
```

[image: uniqueness quantifier with and without spacing]

Here the first lines of each pair have additional spacing of `1.5mu` after the uniqueness quantifier "∃!", while the second lines of each pair don't. For the first pair, the added spacing is as desired; for the second pair, it doesn't look good.

In this example, I would like a `1.5mu` space that disappears at the end of a formula: the same macro should produce lines 1 and 4 above. Perhaps there is a different approach to "∃!", but this serves as one practical example to my general question above.

---

### Example 2

For Heiko Oberdiek's intermediate-length arrows

- `\Implies` (between `\Rightarrow` and `\implies` in length)
- `\Impliedby` (between `\Leftarrow` and `\impliedby` in length)
- `\Iff` (between `\Leftrightarrow` and `\iff` in length)

[defined here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77825), contextual deletion of spacing is desirable on both sides.

Comment: Well perhaps you need to add an explicit math space after the `\existsunique` command, such like `\,` or `\:` (if you prefer it bigger).

Comment: While it is clearly not a binary operator, `\mathbin{\exists!}` works... somewhat.

Comment: @Werner I also considered `\mathop`, but I'd like narrower spacing.

Comment: In `$\mathop{\exists!}x$`, the space between the exclamation mark and the variable is a thin space. Less than this would be almost indistinguishable from no space. Your "idea" is not really correct.

Comment: I'd rather define `\existsunique` as `\exists\mkern-1.5mu!`, rather than adding the space at the right.

Comment: @egreg About `$\mathop{\exists!}x$`: The distance there is too wide for my taste. (One could argue whether one should think of it as a kern – as in "kerning table" – but I wrote `\mskip` instead of `\mkern` since conceptually spaces are the things that can disappear or change in certain places.) // About `\exists\mkern-1.5mu!`: That's a very good idea, though it leaves the general question unsolved. I picked "∃!" instead of "∃" for my example since it seemed easier to argue visually, but bare "∃" has a similar problem because the dual "∀"appears visually further away from what follows.

Comment: @LoverofStructure If you try `$\forall\mathrm{X}$` you can easily see there is *no* added space. I believe you're finding problems where there aren't.

Comment: @egreg 1. I never wrote about "added space". 2. It is more common to see lowercase variables. 3. You don't often use `\mathrm` for variables. 4. Most importantly: If you compare `\(\forall x\)` and `\(\exists x\)`, it's obvious that the kerning is bad (the ∃ appears too close, especially in contrast with ∀). But modifying kerning tables is a hassle, and it has to do with the lettershapes of these two quantifiers (it's a consistent difference between the two), so one working approach would be to deal with it consistently on the character level (as opposed to kerning pairs, for example).

Comment: @LoverofStructure You would need to find a math font where kerning of `\forall` and letters is defined. Good luck with that.

Comment: @tohecz I was gonna add "and where the `\exists` isn't so close to a following letter" - `1mu` or `1.5mu` of kerning can be enough. (In any case - yes, I agree ultimately it's a font design (kerning) issue.)

Answer (score 2):

This revised answer grew out of seeing egreg's answer at [What is the difference of \mathop, \operatorname and \DeclareMathOperator?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84302/what-is-the-difference-of-mathop-operatorname-and-declaremathoperator), where he mentioned this construct: `\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}`

In the OP's question above, Werner and egreg made suggestions using `\mathbin` and `\mathop`, but the OP replied "I also considered `\mathop`, but I'd like narrower spacing."

So taking a tack similar to `\diff`, I came up with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\def\showall{~\fbox{\Longstack{
\text{\detokenize\expandafter{\existsunique}}\\
A \colon  \existsunique y \\
\fboxsep0pt\fbox{$\existsunique$}\\
A \colon  {\existsunique} y
}~}\par}
\begin{document}
\savestack{\Header}{\Longstack{Definition:\\within math:\\boxed:\\brace-isolated:}}
\stackMath
\Header\def\existsunique{\exists!}\showall
\Header\def\existsunique{\exists!\mathop{}\!}\showall
\Header\def\existsunique{\mathop{}\!\exists!\mathop{}\!}\showall
\end{document}
```

[image]

While the actual `\!` kerns may be different than the OP's tastes, perhaps the approach could be adapted to kerns of his choice.

---

ORIGINAL APPROACH:

This solution may (or may not) give you something that works for your application.  I introduce the macro `\mymathop{op-name}{op-definition}{pre-kern}{post-kern}`.

What it does is look at what token follows the new "mymathop", in your case,  `\existsunique`.  If what follow is a `$`, `\)`, or `\egroup`, it prints out the "op definition" by itself; otherwise, it adds the pre- and post-kern about the "op-definition"  (as a side note, the use of `\@ifnextchar` will swallow any intervening spaces between the "mymathop" and the next token).

The `\egroup` catch allows one to force `\mymathop` to suppress the pre-/post-`\kern` even in the middle of a formula, by enclosing it in braces

The MWE below shows it in a formula, fboxed by itself with two of the delimiter styles, and then inside a formula, isolated, with its own set of braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\makeatletter
\def\mymathop#1#2#3#4{%
  \def#1{\@ifnextchar${#2}{\@ifnextchar\){#2}{\@ifnextchar\egroup{#2}{\kern#3#2\kern#4}}}}
}
\makeatother
\mymathop{\existsunique}{\exists!}{0pt}{3pt}
\begin{document}
\(\forall x \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  \existsunique y \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  y^2 = x\)

\fboxsep0pt\fbox{$\existsunique $} \fbox{\(\existsunique \)}

\(\forall x \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  {\existsunique} y \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon
  y^2 = x\)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The macro `\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace` of package `ltxcmds` addresses the spacing problem of `\@ifnextchar` which you mention. (Information taken from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82696).)

Comment: Should one worry about `\endgroup` in addition to `\egroup` (= `}`)?

Comment: @LoverofStructure We are reaching the limits of my competence at this point.  While I know that there are both `\egroup`s and `\endgroup`s, I'm not sure of the distinction of their usage, or whether the techniques of detection differ.  I guess I have more learning to do... :^)

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
\newcommand*{\existsunique}{\thinmuskip=1.5mu\mathop{\exists!}\relax}
```

does what you want.

I think a better solution is

```
    \makeatletter
     \newcommand*{\existsuniquenew}{\@ifnextchar{\)}{\@end}{%
       \@ifnextchar{$}{\@end}{\not@end}}}
     \def\@end{\exists!\relax}%
     \def\not@end{\exists!\mskip1.5mu\relax}
    \makeatother
```

Comment: TeX just marks the points where a thinmuskip has to be used and, when transforming the math list into a horizontal list it uses the current value of `\thinmuskip`. So even enclosing the setting in a group would not work.

Comment: But it does work. You are right: TeX uses the current value of `\thinmuskip`, and after the given definition of `\existunique` and until the end of the current formula, its value is `1.5mu` (sorry, for the awkward looking proof): `\(\forall x \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon \existsunique y \in \mathds{R}^{+}_{0} \colon y^2 = x \quad\text{\the\thinmuskip}\)\qquad \the\thinmuskip` The only problem I see is to avoid another operator in the same formula getting this value (if not necessary).

Comment: @spyglass [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/14996) We love seeing new members in our community. In your case we recommend you creating an account and you then flagging your older post from your new account for merging of the two provisional accounts; that way all of your posts can be attached to the same account.

Comment: @spyglass007 But that's an important concern: you wouldn't want to change the value of `\thinmuskip` for all of its possible uses in the formula.

Comment: @spyglass007 But your second solution is good for makeshift purposes. I'd give it one upvote (for its practical use) if you edited your question to take the points from this comment thread into account.

Comment: Forget 'bout it.